# "Obsolete" warning when trying to listen to NSNotification and how to stop observing?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a helper method which encrypts some data on the iPhone. If the operatin is interrupted because the device gets locked, I want to delete the file I have just been processing. Therefore I add a notifiaction listsner if the method is called.

Two issues: 
1. I get a warning that the method I use to add the listener is obsolete. How else would I do it?
2. If processing is done I would like to get rid of the listener - but how?

```
private static foo(string sDestPathAndFile)
{
  NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ( "UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable", 
  delegate( NSNotification oNotification )
  {
    Util.DeleteFile ( sDestPathAndFile );
    throw new InvalidOperationException ( "Protected data became unavailable - device locked?" );
  } );

  // Do some processing here.
  // ...
  // Now get rid of the notification listener - but how?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the obsolete warning, you should use the following:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.ProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable, Handler);
```

This applies to all observers, e.g.:

```
UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification
UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification
UIDevice.OrientationDidChangeNotification
```

and so on. These are the appropriate `NSString`'s that `NSNotificationCenter` is expecting.

As for getting rid of it, I can't verify this first hand as I'm currently not in a position to do so but one possible way is:

Declare the addobserver as an NSObject, then use the `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver` to remove it:

```
NSObject obj = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.ProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable, handler);

// do whatever you need to do
// time to remove:
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(obj);
```